# Is there better way to implement Scheduler based project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, architecture

In My Team we have lot of similar project,

1. which fetches the data from central hub periodically and save it to local db.
2. We create Elastic Data index from local db.
3. We have backend module to Provide this elastic data to UI Dashboard.

[image: Architecture diagram would be as follows]

Is there any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Need more data:

1. What is the data size in central hub?
2. What is the growth of data in central hub?
3. How much time it takes per schedule?
4. Should your data from central hub to Elastic Index be on real time/immediate OR delay is okay?

Assuming it is a large data set, here is another option:

Option 1: What you have above
Option 2: If you have eventing mechanism from central hub, you can replace data refresh module with event listeners pumping data from events to Elastic Index Builder.

**Option 1:**

**Pros:**

1. Simple to implement

**Cons:**

1. You need to query central hub periodically - this puts additional load on Central Hub
2. If the growth of data is large, this approach is not scalable to read all data with every schedule
3. If time per schedule is is x hours, your processing speed per schedule needs to be < x.
4. With growth in data, delay might increase
5. What happens if there is failure? rerun the scheduler? Now it is getting complicated.

**Option 2:**

**Pros:**

1. Highly scalable - even though data in Central hub is growing
2. You may not need a DB for copying data
3. Events can be retried if there is failure
4. If there is a change in Central hub, that data can show up in the
   index < few seconds (most of the time)

**Cons:**

1. Eventing is another infrastructure you need to maintain, but there are well tested open source & commercial products to suit your needs.